# Why am i facing this and what is workflow

Tags: java

Could anyone please help in understanding the StackOverFlowError at runtime in below code.
I am not able to understand workflow.
One of the interview Question:)

```
public class Interview {

    Interview i1 = new Interview();
    Interview(){
        System.out.println("Hello");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Interview i = new Interview();

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the word "workflow" mean to you?

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor is initializing itself. This is what your constructor looks like to the JVM:

```
Interview i1;
Interview(){
    super();
    i1 = new Interview(); // this line calls the constructor
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Interview i1 = new Interview();` says that each `Interview` has its *own* `Interview` object that belongs to it, and so once you call `new Interview()` in `main`, the system starts trying to create a new `Interview` for that one, and a new `Interview` for that one...

It never even makes it to the (explicit) constructor, because the system goes off on a never-ending chain of new `Interview`s first. You should almost certainly remove the `i1` field from the `Interview` class.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new `Interview` every time you instantiate an `Interview`. This leads to a never-ending cycle of constructor calls and instantiations, which eventually run out your stack space (because the function calls take stack space).

Note that if you had infinite stack space available to you, you would eventually fail from all the `Interview` objects being allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Because once you initialize that first `Interview()` in `main()` it creates and initializes a second `Interview`, which creates and initializes another and so on.

Answer (score 0):

All initialization you do at the fields would become the part of the parameter-less constructor(in your case).

So,your code would become

```
public class Interview 
{

    Interview i1;
    Interview()
    {
        super();//by default calls the constructor of Object
        i1 = new Interview();//initialization becomes part of constructor
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

Now this would recursively instatiate Interview causing exception